# How to reduce time for block confirmation in the Ethereum blockchain and also time to listen to logs emitted?

Tags: blockchain, events, logs, confirmations

I am designing an application in which I am emitting logs through transactions in the Ethereum blockchain. I also created an event listener to listen to the new logs emitted. But I want time from emitting logs to the event listener to respond to it to be in few milliseconds.
But the problem here is the time taken to create a block is around 12 seconds and to get 5-6 blocks confirmations takes around 2-3 minutes which kills my service time and makes it difficult for real-time usage.

Any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Ethereum, but use some other blockchain that provides faster block times. E.g. [NEAR EVM shard](https://github.com/near/near-evm) can do sub-1 second blocks.

You are still not going to see millisecond times, because of the limit of light speed. The blockchain must stay synchronous around the world.

Comment: is it good to trust these other networks than Ethereum?